# Convergence of series of normally distributed random variables

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, probability-limit-theorems

$X_1, X_2,...$ are independent and each $X_n$ has normal distribution $N(0,a^n)$ for $a>0$.
I need to find probability that the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n$$ converges.
How do I approach this problem?

Comment: It looks like an exercise in both Borel Cantelli Lemmas. It's probably easier to think of it as $\sum_{n=1} \sqrt{a}^n Z_n$ where each $Z_n$ is standard normal.

Comment: For instance, for $a\geq 1,$ you should be able to prove that there is some $\varepsilon>0$ such that $Z_n>\varepsilon$ infinitely often with probability $1$.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Care to clarify? B-C lemma involves sum $\sum P(X_n)$, how do I get from this to convergence of series of rv's?

Comment: @WoolierThanThou From your second comment I see how I can use it to prove divergence, but how to prove convergence?

Comment: Well, you can just use Kavi's proof, but you can also end up estimating, say, $\mathbb{P}(|Z_n|\geq a^{-n/4})$ and apply, say, the Chebyshev inequality, to get that these probabilities are summable. Hence, $\sqrt{a}^n |Z_n|\leq a^{n/4}$ eventually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hints: the series converges with probability $0$ or $1$ by $0-1$ law.

If $a <1$ then $\sum E|X_n| <\infty$ so the series converges with probability $1$.

If $a=1$ the series converges with probability $0$. In fact no i.i.d. series converges except when the terms are all $0$ with probability $1$.

When  $a>1$ it is easy to see that $|X_n|$  tends to $\infty$ in probability which implies that the series cannot converges with probability $1$ and hence it converges with probability $0$.

You can also solve this problem using Kolmogorov's 3-series theorem.

Comment: "In fact no i.i.d. series converges except when the terms are all 0 with probability 1." Is that "In fact no i.i.d. series converges (except when the terms are all 0) with probability 1." or "In fact no i.i.d. series converges (except when the terms are all 0 with probability 1)."?

Comment: @Acccumulation There is no difference between the two because countable union of null sets is a null set.